# IIS & PHP pages not rendering properly in Chrome only

Tags: php, google-chrome, iis

I just configured my development machine to for PHP with IIS. I mostly develop using ASP.NET, hence I already have IIS running.

The setup works ok with one exception. When i create pages with PHP and load them using internet explorer or mozilla firefox, the output is as expected. All the styles and images work correctly. But when I load the same pages in Chrome, all i get is plain text and html elements without any style at all. Also the images will not display.

ASP.NET pages work fine in all the 3 browsers. But the PHP pages won't work in Chrome. I just don't understand.

I'm running Windows 10, Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73, IIS version 1511 (OS Build 10586.11).

Comment: Press f12 in chrome & check the network panel. Is your css being loaded?

Comment: I have checked and its not being loaded. Also the images and script files are not loaded. It says (failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Just found the problem. It was my Ad Blocker. Disabled it for my domain and now all is well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The developer console is always your friend :)